KiCad .pos export for OpenPnP
I need setup pick and place machine driven by OpenPnP. I can export .pos file from KiCad PCB and import into OpenPnP. But I would like to avoid many trial/error iterations with matching orientation and position on real PCB.

Does there exist a visualization tool of placement (.pos) on Gerber files?
How is the X-Y position defined in .pos file? Is it computed center of component or origin of component model? I remember e.g. some component models having wrong center of rotation off center. I need also consider also some parts with asymmetrical package having pads along one side.
What about orientation angle?


Wouldn't the X,Y center positions be the origins in the footprints?  In that case, where the center is depends entirely on how the footprints were drawn and you would have to look at each footprint file to figure out where it is on the part.  Usually, that's at the center of the part, or at the coordinate origins given in the datasheet footprint info.  But someone can draw the footprint however they like so don't count on it.

Yes, you are right. It is related to footprint origin. CCW rotation is positive angle. I found NextPCB's HQDFM rather mighty tool for pre-manufacture/assembly tests. It can match visually centriod csv file on Gerber. But it is rather complicated and packages are matched and visualized to their library. Good for PCBA processed at NextPCB.
